# Receive unexpected output from TCPDF

Tags: laravel, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF with Laravel.
while using `$tcpdf->Output()` it showing me some object of tcpdf
Output:
[This is what I got as output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56lx0.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is the content of the pdf file that was created. If you give `$tcpdf->Output('myfile.pdf','F')` it will put all that content in the file 'myfile.pdf' on your server. If you want the file to be downloaded as soon as it is created you need to just specify the filename eg. `$tcpdf->Output('myfile.pdf')`.

For more detail read https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/classes-TCPDF/#method_Output